# Is there anything to do with Duplicate Holocards after you have completed all of the sets?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-2016

Once you have completed all of the holo card sets I assume you still continue to get them. Is there any way to turn Duplicate cards into Bolts or Raritanium or are they just going to continue to go up and just sit around until you can't carry anymore?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, sadly you can't trade in extra Holocards once you've completed every set. But by then, you shouldn't have to be worrying about Bolts (as you'd most likely have every weapon and their Omega variant in Challenge Mode, meaning you'd only need them for ammo and health unless you're playing with the infinite ammo/health cheats) or Raritanium so much.